# Can I turn a string into variables for a struct in C++?

Tags: csv, struct

The title pretty much says it all, I was wondering if there is a function to transform a string, specifically one extracted from a .csv file, to values for filling a struct with variables of different types. Thank you very much for your attention.

EDIT: I added the .csv file, and a snippet to understand the variables in it. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQcUX.png

```
'''
struct Line
{
    int ID;
    string date;
    string supplier;
    int first_dose;
    int second_dose;
    int booster_dose;
    int sesso_femminile;
    int sesso_maschile;
    string region;
};
'''
```

Comment: Can you please send an image (from the .csv for example) to show us these fields/variables ? It will be clearer.

Comment: Sent everything